# What is the use of label in hook_entity_info

Tags: drupal-7

What is the use of label in hook_entity_info, i am not able to figure out the purpose and use of it.

```
function hook_entity_info() {
  $return['model'] = array(
    'label' => t('Model'),
```

Answer (score 0):

The label is the human-readable name of the entity type. Generally speaking, the label property of a field/node/entity could be used for display purpose, hence the use of the t() function.

Source : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7